# Pandas to MYSQL only writing one line to the table

Tags: python, mysql

I am trying to read a csv and export into my MYSQL database. Here is the code:

```
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine, types

engine = create_engine 
('mysql://admin:password@name.cj4ghwejxvaa.us- 

east-2.rds.amazonaws.com/namedev')


df = pd.read_csv 
   ("C:/Users/Name/PycharmProjects/colors/Model 
   Files/currentfeb.txt",sep=' ', names=["Longtiude", "Latitude", "Value"])

df.to_sql(name='currentfebTry9', con=engine, index=False)
```

Below is the output. As you can see, only the headers are
printed.
[image]

Here are the first 5 lines in currentfeb.txt

```
 -179.979166666666657 89.9791666666666714 -3.39999995214436425e+38
 -179.9375 89.9791666666666714 -3.39999995214436425e+38
 -179.895833333333343 89.9791666666666714 -3.39999995214436425e+38
 -179.854166666666657 89.9791666666666714 -3.39999995214436425e+38
 -179.8125 89.9791666666666714 -3.39999995214436425e+38
```

Thanks in advance.

Here is the dataframe:

```
  Longtiude   Latitude         Value
  0        -179.979167  89.979167 -3.400000e+38
  1        -179.937500  89.979167 -3.400000e+38
  2        -179.895833  89.979167 -3.400000e+38
  3        -179.854167  89.979167 -3.400000e+38
  4        -179.812500  89.979167 -3.400000e+38
  ...              ...        ...           ...
  37324795  179.812500 -89.979167 -2.498000e+01
  37324796  179.854167 -89.979167 -2.498000e+01
  37324797  179.895833 -89.979167 -2.498000e+01
  37324798  179.937500 -89.979167 -2.498000e+01
  37324799  179.979167 -89.979167 -2.001200e+01

  [37324800 rows x 3 columns]
```

Comment: Could you show us the `df`? Try printing it

Comment: Okay, please see my edit.

Comment: I feel as though it may have to do with types of the data.

Comment: I did this: df=df.astype(str) to change everything to a string. Same result.

Comment: What datatype should I convert the data frame to. String? Float? Thank you.

Comment: You need to have your data line up with the types in sql. If you're feeding the headers into the rows, then the columns need to be strings, which means the data you put into the sql database are strings too.